# How to add merge field while inserting a table using Office.js inside the body of a document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, add-in, office-addins

How to add mail merge field while inserting a table using Office.js inside the body of a document .

For creating a table below code is working but I want to insert merge field while creating  table.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;

            body.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end, [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]);

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync();
        }).catch(function (e) {

            console.log(e.message);
        })
```

Comment: @Cindy Meister please let me know if you know the answer for this question. Thank you

Comment: The problem with inserting fields using the JS APIs is that there is no proviso for it. Since Word on-line doesn't support working with fields, it's not part of the JS APIs. There are requests on UserVoice to implement it... So the only possibility, currently, is to insert the field codes as Word Open XML. It's not clear from the question where the merge field should be, in relation to the table. But the choice would be to insert the table plus field code(s) as one Word Open XML string, or to insert the table then add the Word Open XML for the field code after-the-fact, in the correct range.

Comment: Note: in order to "ping" someone the name needs to be written correctly. That would be with no spaces between parts of the name. I just happened to see this because I monitor everything in the ms-word tag.

Comment: Yes merge field should be relation to the table, while inserting table  merge field should be inserted inside table row

Comment: If you create a document with only this table plus the merge field, save it, then open it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool you'll be able to see the Word Open XML, as well as the Open XML SDK code to create the document and the table. This will give you the basis for generating the ooxml that can be used with the JS API. For more information, see the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister I saw above link and tried as you said after running the code I am getting this error " We are sorry we can't open the document msoD772.temp because we found a problem with its Contents " 

Details : unspecified error, Location : line:1,

Comment: The error means the Word Open XML being pushed into the document is not valid.

Comment: how to create custom xml tag that should be hidden in word document

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "custom xml tag that should be hidden in the document".

Comment: After adding merge field  how to move cursor to the end of merge field using xml ? . I tried in word document and checked in productivity tool but that xml [ <w:bookmarkStart w:name=\"_GoBack\" w:id=\"0\" /><w:bookmarkEnd w:id=\"0\" /> ] is not working.

Comment: Could you please post this as a *new question*, with a [mcve] so that we can see the *code context*. In general terms, you'd need to get the Range and then put the focus at the end of it. But exactly how to do that will depend on the code that gets you to that point...